# Harnessing the power of Unix commands in Windows

Tags: linux, bash, unix, cmd

Is there any way to have commands like `grep`, `sed`, `wget` etc (basically the **can't do without** commands of Unix/Linux) in Windows ?

Comment: [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com)

Comment: MinGW/MSYS, GnuWin32, UnxUtils, and half a dozen others. Or, `.configure && make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) or [minGW](http://www.mingw.org/), whichever floats your boat. To get access to the linux commands in shells like `cmd` or `PowerShell` you should add the `bin`-directory to your path.

Beware though that sometimes this means that the cygwin/mingw-installed applications can `overshadow` other installed applications. Take a look in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613586/conflicting-cygwin-and-windows-path) for more information

Answer (score 1):

Download the UnxUtils porting to Windows